What are the effects of "Show new snippet experience (experimental)" setting in Visual Studio 2022?
Recently, I have encountered a new option in Visual Studio 2022 "Show new snippet experience (experimental)" setting in Visual Studio 2022?".
It is located in the VS Options: "Text Editor" -> "C#" -> "IntelliSense" section:

I enabled this setting but I can't observe any difference in my snippets behavior. I also couldn't find any description of this property in Google.
Could you please describe what is does?

Not 100% sure but my guess is it's probably something to do with an enhanced code snippets UX/UI. You might not want to turn it on however as this video (from 2 months ago) explains there's a bug with it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1OKNZo3Ju0

Thanks for the warning @AlexD!
I will disable it, but I still would like to know what it does.
